# JAXB dependency in multimodule gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jaxb, multi-module

I have a `spring-boot` application with modules. Structure looks something like this:

```
|- commons
|- jaxb
|- main
```

`commons` is not important here

**jaxb** `build.gradle`:

```
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    
    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }
    
    jar {
        enabled = true
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':commons')

        api 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.0.1'
        api 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1'
        api 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:3.0.2'
    
        ...
    }
```

**main** `build.gradle`:

```
    apply plugin: "java"
       
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':commons')
        implementation project(':jaxb')

        ...
    }
```

Build works properly, but when I try to run the application it ends with exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException

Does anyone know why `jaxb` dependencies are not available at runtime? Do I really need to declare them in `main` module in addition to the `jaxb` module? Maybe I'm missing something in `jaxb` module `build.gradle`?

I'm using: `openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15`

Comment: What's the command you use to run the app?

Comment: I'm using `jib` to build a docker container and run it or I'm run it directly from IDE (Intellij). The result is the same in both cases.

This is a `jib` part from `build.gradle`:
```
jib {
    from {
        image = 'gcr.io/distroless/java:11'
    }
    to {
        image = 'example/jaxb-app'
    }
    container {
        ports = ['8080']
        mainClass = 'com.example.jaxb.Application'
        jvmFlags = ['-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=80.0', '-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0']
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try unzip the output JAR to see whether the packaged classes are correct. Does this command work: `./gradlew bootrun`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I didn't have time to check this earlier.
I checked everything again and the only place where it doesn't work is in the IDE (I'm using IntelliJ 2021.2.2 Community)
So I can build and run docker image and `gradle bootrun` works